# How to automatically handle messages in server?

Tags: c#, client-server

I have TCP and UDP classes. I've created a Dictionary for handlers. This was okay for a small number of message types but now I need to extend my app and I would like to handle receiving messages (or packets) automatically; not hard-coded in a dictionary.

```
public void ConnectToServer()
{
    tcp = new TCP();
    udp = new UDP();
    InitializeClientData();
    isConnected = true;
    tcp.Connect(); 
}

private void InitializeClientData()
{
    packetHandlers = new Dictionary<int, PacketHandler>()
    {
        { (int)ServerPackets.welcome, ClientHandle.Welcome },
        { (int)ServerPackets.spawnPlayer, ClientHandle.SpawnPlayer },
        { (int)ServerPackets.playerPosition, ClientHandle.PlayerPosition },
        { (int)ServerPackets.playerRotation, ClientHandle.PlayerRotation },
        { (int)ServerPackets.playerDisconnected, ClientHandle.PlayerDisconnected },
        { (int)ServerPackets.playerHealth, ClientHandle.PlayerHealth },
        { (int)ServerPackets.playerRespawned, ClientHandle.PlayerRespawned }
    };
    Debug.Log("Initialized packets.");
}
```

Do you know a generic way to handle incoming messages automatically without registering a dictionary manually like "InitilizeClientData"? How can I do this?

Comment: _Somewhere_ you'll have to map handlers to messages. Here you have it all in one place. You could introduce an interface, IMessageHandler with a property that reports the message number it can handle (or a CanHandle(int), but you don't want to loop over all handlers for each message), then register them using DI/reflection (Scrutor) on startup?

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the very quick response.  In any way, I need to map it as I understand it correctly.